# C# WPF Rectangle Fill Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I need to bind color to fill the rectangle.

XAML:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Colorr}"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Height="3" Width="16"
           Margin="3, 1, 5, 0" 
           Visibility="Visible"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ItemViewModel()
{
     Colorr = Colors.Red;;
}
public Color Colorr
{
    get {
        return color; }
    set
    {
        color = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Colorr);
    }
}
```

The resulting rectangle is not visible (or is transparent - it's hard to say...) instead of being visible and red. How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: do not use `Color` instead use `SolidColorBrush`.

Comment: Did you set the DataContext? If you hard-code the color in Xaml can you see the rectangle?

Comment: @FelixD. - using `Brush` instead od `Color` helped :) 
@MartinoBordin - yes, if I set the color in xaml i can see the rectangle, but it doesn't fit my needs - the color must be changed dynamic. No, I don't set the data context in this `rectangle`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Rectangle.Fill`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.fill(v=vs.110).aspx) (which it inherits from `Shape`) is a `Brush`, not a `Color`. So make your property a `Brush` instead:

```
private Brush _colorr = Brushes.Red;
public Brush Colorr
{
    get
    {
        return _colorr;
    }
    set
    {
        _colorr = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Colorr);
    }
}
```

There may be other problems, but you need to fix this one first.

Comment: Thank you - it works and there are no more problems... so far :)

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak "No more problems so far" is the best any of us can ever say in this racket. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

The other way around is to use `ColorToBrushConverter`, just like the one below:

```
 using System.Windows.Data;
 using System.Windows.Media;

 public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
 {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush((Color)value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (value as SolidColorBrush).Color;
        }
 }
```

Then in XAML define the converter as resource and use it like this:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Colorr, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made minor changes to the Color BrushConverter proposed by Vaidas's to take care of the possible null reference exception:

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
    
    namespace Common.Client.Wpf.Converters
{
    public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value is null ? null : new SolidColorBrush((Color)value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (value as SolidColorBrush)?.Color;
        }
    }
}
```